# Will the count of column values change after doing a self join in sql

Tags: sql, join, self-join

I am getting confused in the output of my table after performing a self join
For eg : this my table

```
select * from Logins
id  login_date 
7   2020-05-30
1   2020-05-30
7   2020-05-31
7   2020-05-01
7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-03
1   2020-05-07
7   2020-05-10
```

and the output after running the query

```
select * from Logins a join Logins b on a.id = b.id
 is :
id  login_date  id  login_date
7   2020-05-30  7   2020-05-30
7   2020-05-31  7   2020-05-30
7   2020-05-01  7   2020-05-30
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-30
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-30
7   2020-05-03  7   2020-05-30
7   2020-05-10  7   2020-05-30
1   2020-05-30  1   2020-05-30
1   2020-05-07  1   2020-05-30
7   2020-05-30  7   2020-05-31
7   2020-05-31  7   2020-05-31
7   2020-05-01  7   2020-05-31
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-31
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-31
7   2020-05-03  7   2020-05-31
7   2020-05-10  7   2020-05-31
7   2020-05-30  7   2020-05-01
7   2020-05-31  7   2020-05-01
7   2020-05-01  7   2020-05-01
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-01
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-01
7   2020-05-03  7   2020-05-01
7   2020-05-10  7   2020-05-01
7   2020-05-30  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-31  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-01  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-03  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-10  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-30  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-31  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-01  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-03  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-10  7   2020-05-02
7   2020-05-30  7   2020-05-03
7   2020-05-31  7   2020-05-03
7   2020-05-01  7   2020-05-03
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-03
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-03
7   2020-05-03  7   2020-05-03
7   2020-05-10  7   2020-05-03
1   2020-05-30  1   2020-05-07
1   2020-05-07  1   2020-05-07
7   2020-05-30  7   2020-05-10
7   2020-05-31  7   2020-05-10
7   2020-05-01  7   2020-05-10
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-10
7   2020-05-02  7   2020-05-10
7   2020-05-03  7   2020-05-10
7   2020-05-10  7   2020-05-10
```

53 rows.

why is the self join giving the table b date value to every date value in a?
shouldnt it simply be something like

```
id  login_date  id  login_date 
7   5/30/2020   7   5/30/2020
1   5/30/2020   1   5/30/2020
7   5/31/2020   7   5/31/2020
7   5/1/2020    7   5/1/2020
7   5/2/2020    7   5/2/2020
7   5/2/2020    7   5/2/2020
7   5/3/2020    7   5/3/2020
1   5/7/2020    1   5/7/2020
7   5/10/2020   7   5/10/2020
```

where table b is a replica or just another table like table a. I imagined self join as nothing but creating a table replica and joining it with itself.

I am just getting to know sql and this basic join function has got me confused or maybe its something very silly I am missing here.
Please help.

Comment: If there are 2 rows with id 1, your (self) join will return 2 * 2 rows with id 1.

Comment: 7 =  7 * 7 rows = 49, 1 = 2 * 2 rows = 4, 49 + 4 = 53

Comment: The problem starts with having a column called `ID` that doesn't identify a row as its name suggests. If it were unique as it should be, however, a self-join would make no sense, as you'd join each row to itself, thus gaining nothing. As is, you just join on some column that is mistakenly called ID, but is not unique, so you create all tuple combinations within an ID, as has already been exlained.

Comment: To complete this: If you wanted to join the rows so that not only the ID but also the date matches, you would have to tell the DBMS so: `on a.id = b.id and a.login_date = b.login_date`.

Comment: When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help] [mre] Otherwise you're just asking for yet another presentation of the language without out knowing what you already misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

The IDs in the table aren't unique. So every row with some ID is matched to ALL the rows with that ID in the joined table. E.g., you have two rows with ID `1` in the table. Each of them is matched to each of them in the joined table for a total of 2*2=4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is how join works: for each row from first values all rows from second table with corresponding join key are returned. So, id join key is not unique, join duplicates records. You have `7` rows with `id = 7`, it gives you `7*7=49` rows with `id=7` and `2` rows with `id=1` result in `2x2=4` rows with `id=1`, totally `53` rows.

Answer (score 0):

To get this result:

```
id  login_date  id  login_date 
7   5/30/2020   7   5/30/2020
1   5/30/2020   1   5/30/2020
7   5/31/2020   7   5/31/2020
7   5/1/2020    7   5/1/2020
7   5/2/2020    7   5/2/2020
7   5/2/2020    7   5/2/2020
7   5/3/2020    7   5/3/2020
1   5/7/2020    1   5/7/2020
7   5/10/2020   7   5/10/2020
```

Try this code,

```
select * from Logins a 
join Logins b 
on a.id = b.id AND a.login_date = b.login_date.
```

In this query you will be comparing both the columns so that you will get the expected result.

Comment: Even easier: `select id, login_date, id, login_date from Logins`